# Do external DVD drives other than a SuperDrive work with the MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I need to access a DVD using my MacBook Air, and am planning to buy an external drive. I'd prefer going for an option cheaper than the SuperDrive.

However it looks like the [SuperDrive doesn't work with other machines](http://www.engadget.com/2008/01/24/confirmed-macbook-air-superdrive-does-not-work-with-other-machi/), and this worries me that other drives won't work with this machine.

If I get a recently manufactured non-Apple external drive, can I expect it to work with my MacBook Air?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SuperDrive does only work with the MacBook Air, but the MacBook Air supports a lot of other drives.

For example there is the [Asus External-Optical-SDRW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YT578O) ($37,75). Cheap, fairly fast and not very ugly :)
[image]

Or the [Samsung External-Optical-SE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0044DEDBG). ($45,80) A bit more expensive, but it support way more formats and speeds:
[image]